# What's going on with the scale/length here in edit mode?

Tags: modeling, units

I am working on a 3D model for printing. I have my scene set to a `Unit Scale = 0.001` and `Length = Millimeters`. This makes it the correct size for the printer. I also updated my scale on grids to 0.001.

I'm trying to make a box with a 3mm thick wall. I added a box to the scene and changed the dimensions to what I need.

[image]

Then I went to the top face and did an inset. If I'm in the top view and use the numbers I can type 0.03 and see that it is three grid squares (i.e. 3mm) inset but in the info header it says 3 micro meters. Not sure what's going on there.

Then I set the origin of the box to the bottom face and did an extrude of the inset to bring the top face down leaving 3mm on the bottom wall too; as evidenced by the 3 grid squares. This results in the Z position of the points being "0.066667" mm. Shouldn't it be 3mm?

[image]

I really don't understand what's going on with the units on the box. Does it have something to do with the "scale" on the box being not "1"? Should I have changed the dimensions of the box a different way?

Comment: Hello :). This has everything to do with the *Scale* of your object. Go to *Object > Apply > Scale* to set it back to 1. Then the transforms will be correct.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. Do you want to reply as an answer so I can accept it? Also quick note that in 2.8 `CTRL+A` is how you get the apply option.